# r sqldf query returns NA in values returned from joined table

Tags: r, sqldf

I have code that loads some data and three dataframes. I am using `ClassificationCleanUpData` as a lookup data to clean classifications to be more generic.

The rows from the `WorkData` show as `NA` even though the results are being listed. If I reverse the query the rows from `ClassificationCleanUpData` show up as `NA`. If I query either one, I get results. I am getting results which means the join works it is just not returning the correct data, but showing `NA`. How do I get the actual data to show in both tables.

I am using R studio with the `sqldf` library

```
library(sqldf)

WorkData <- MetObjects[,c(3,5,22,23,24,39 )]
WorkData$Object.Mean.Date <- round((WorkData$Object.Begin.Date +         WorkData$Object.End.Date)/2,0)

#import new classifications
ClassificationCleanUpData <- read.csv(file =     WorkingFile2,fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")

WorkDataFinalSTR <- "SELECT WorkData.*, ClassificationCleanUpData.Old, ClassificationCleanUpData.New FROM ClassificationCleanUpData left join WorkData on WorkData.Classification = ClassificationCleanUpData.Old"
WorkDataFinal <- sqldf(WorkDataFinalSTR)
```

I should return nine rows with the actual values from the tables
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJccg.png)
and
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xq24.png)
and
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7cbm.png)

Comment: We can't really answer your question without seeing sample data for both tables, along with the expected outcome.  Can you add that data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added three images, it would not allow me to edit the descriptions. The first image is the outcome of all 500K rows of data, the second is the ClassificationCleanUpData data, and the third is WorkData

Comment: Doesn't help.  _Delete_ those image links, and include _text_ please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please help us help you. Without actual data, something we can copy and paste, it's going to be impossible to lend a hand. Share a small piece of your data

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out.